# Why use "Team" while voting?

Tags: grammar, phrases, verbs, urban-legends

While I'm surfing the online forum and social media about Godzilla VS Kong movie, I found lots of people said Team Godzilla & Team Kong to mean Support Godzilla & Support Kong.

I want to know why "team" is equivalent to support or vote in this situation.

Comment: I don't really understand your question; you should rephrase it more precisely.

Comment: I didn't have enough time to edit my comment. Are you asking about the use of "team" in that particular context? To start, it is not used as a verb, as you may think, it is used as a noun. When someone says "I'm team Godzilla", means he's joining the supporters of Godzilla, as a group of people sharing a common interest (in this case, Godzilla's victory against Kong). You can say "I'm on team Godzilla", which is the long version of it. The noun "team" is usually used like this in cases where there are different forces that are going to fight against each other (literally or figuratively).

Comment: I've always considered this to be a Britishism, though it's been well-established in the US for 10-20 years.  It simply refers to a group of avid supporters.

Comment: That's odd, @HotLicks, I always thought we got it from you. However it's been around in the UK a lot longer than 20 years so it must've been a British native abomination.

Comment: @BoldBen - You didn't get it from me!

Comment: @HotLicks I accept that, it's our own, supposedly trendy, fault!